# prepositions and capitalize

Tags: prepositions

I am very confused about capitalizing prepositions in titles. I just can't seem to get it. I've googled and read a lot.

In the following sentence, should "to" be capitalized? Why? I know some say don't capitalize short words, but others say capitalize short prepositions that act as adverbs, adjectives, or verbs. Doesn't this "to" act as an adverb?

I read the book, "How To Eat Fast at School".

Comment: Please clarify "prepositions that act as adverbs, adjectives, r verbs".

Comment: For "prepositions that act as adverbs," I think OP may be referring to *phrasal verbs* like "step **on**" or "jump **over**."

Comment: In your example, the word "to" should not be capitalized (although *to* isn't actually a preposition here: it's the "sign" of the infinitive). You're correct that the preposition "at" should also be lowercase. The rule I learned was that "unimportant words" (i.e. prepositions, the "to" in the infinitive, and conjunctions) don't get capitalized in a title *unless* they're the *first* word in the title.

Comment: Here is a more detailed set of guidelines: https://www.scribbr.com/mla/titles/#capitalization-in-mla-titles (note the distinction made between coordinating and subordinating conjunctions)

Comment: There are differences between American and British usage. I've noticed that Americans capitalise more words than we British do, for example in newspaper headlines.

Answer (score 3):

[thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/title-case/) recommends

> **Don’t capitalize prepositions (at, by, to, etc.)**
> ... prepositions should not be capitalized—unless a style guide recommends capitalizing them if they are a **long word** [emphasis added].

The *to* in your example is not a preposition but should be treated similar to one.  This is considered one of the **minor words** described in *thesaurus.com*.

Certain **minor** words need capitalisation, however:

> Capitalize the first and sometimes the last word

> Capitalize words that have four letters or more

Different style guides have their own recommendations.  If you need to follow a specific style guide, you should do so.